# Change of font size of Windows CE command line shell?

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

is there any chance to change the font size of the Windows CE command line shell (\windows\cmd.exe)? 
I would like to use a smaller font, so more text can be displayed on small displays (eg 320x240).

Thanks for any help.

Regards, Timm.